# missfont.log in home directory?

Tags: home-directory, log, evince

On a clean install I get a file called **missfont.log** in my home directory as well as in other directories in which I open pdfs. I don't want it there.

How can I avoid this log to be created? One of the following bug reports speaks of installing tetex-bin, but I cannot find it: [bug1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/42410) and [bug2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/53452).

Answer (score 2):

**edit**: this solution did *not* work after all. all suggestions are welcome.

I found a solution, but it is not flawless. Apparently the bug is related to dvips. I added a file `.dvips` in my home folder and tried to redefine the `MISSFONT_LOG` variable. The latter is very poorly documented, so feel free to add the correct version. I tried the following and I am no longer getting missfont.log files all over the place (also no .missfont.log files, though).

```
MISSFONT_LOG = $HOME/.missfont.log 
MISSFONT_LOG = .missfont.log
MISSFONT_LOG : .missfont.log
```